# How to replace a value after the second to last occurrence of a string in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
declare @test varchar(50) = 'F-1084-002-04-009'
```

I need to replace the value inside the last two dashes to "00"

So it should be this:

```
F-1084-002-00-009
```

I'm struggling to find the easiest way to do this.

Comment: Are they alwass a fixed number of characters to the right? If so, you can use the `stuff()` function

Comment: the format is the same, the numbers change. i'll look into stuff.

Comment: If they are fixed length you can also "cheat" with LEFT() + AddString+ RIGHT()

Answer (score 1):

If the format is always the same you could do this:

```
 select stuff('F-1084-002-04-009', 12, 2, '00')
```

Comment: unfortunately the format isn't always the same. the numbers could vary, so all I need to figure out now is how to get the "12" .. which could be a different number

Comment: Can you give me a couple other examples? Just so I know we're talking about the same thing

Comment: here's another example: F-0-001-00-003

Comment: basically i just need to make sure i replace whatever value is between the last two dashes with "00"

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select *,
    charindex('-', reverse(v), 0) Last,
    charindex('-', reverse(v), charindex('-', reverse(v), 0)+1) Second_Last,
    left(v, len(v)-(charindex('-', reverse(v), charindex('-', reverse(v), 0)+1)))
        + '-00'
        +right(v, charindex('-', reverse(v), 0))
from t
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as a separate answer because while I'm pretty happy with it, it's a little bit unconventional. However it is quite robust even if you make absolutely no assumptions about how many groups there are or how many characters are in each group.

The first two table variables are just setup data. I used your test examples and added a third of my own. I also created a small auto-incrementing tally table. Id recommend having one of these persisted on your DB somewhere if you don't already.

```
declare @src table (val)
insert into @src (Val)
values
    ('F-0-001-99-003'),
    ('F-1084-002-04-009'),
    ('FF-1-02-345-9')

declare @tally table (idx)
insert into @tally (idx)
select top 100 row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1 -- 0 based
from sys.all_objects
```

Now we begin work in earnest. I used a trick I learned from writing SQL comma-delimited-string splitters to quickly get the indexes of all the hyphens in the string. What I'm interested in here is the second to last hyphen (which starts the section we want to replace) and the last hyphen (which denotes its end). I add 1 to it because computers are just like that.

Now I need to get the row with the highest index, and the second highest index. I went about this with a row_number and a group by, but I suspect there are other ways to get at it as well.

So for the final select, we have the starting index of the slug we want to replace, the ending index, as well as its length (which I just saved off as an additional column for brevity.

And at *this* point, my original solution using `stuff` works.

```
;with hyphenIndexes as
(
    select 
        RID = row_number() over (partition by s.Val order by idx desc),
        Val, 
        Idx = Idx + 1
    from @src s
    inner join @tally t
        on t.idx <= len(val)
    where substring(val, idx, 1) = '-'
), almostDone as
(
    select 
        Val,
        StartIndex = max(iif(RID = 2, idx, null)),
        EndIndex = max(Idx),
        SlugLength = max(Idx) - max(iif(RID = 2, idx, null)) - 1
    from hyphenIndexes
    group by Val
)
select
    OriginalString = val,
    ReplacedString = stuff
        (
            Val, 
            StartIndex, 
            SlugLength,
            replicate('0', SlugLength)
        ) 
from almostDone
```

I should note that it's late in the day and my brain is pretty fried, so there might be ways to make this more succinct. I also broke things out quite a bit for clarity. I also approached it from the standpoint that the strings could be all mannar of whackness, and it would still work. However if you're able to make any assumption about the number of groups or the number of characters per group, I suspect you could skip several steps I've done in here.

Answer (score 0):

```
 - Simple way is to Use Substring to find what you want to Replace.And
   use Replace Function to Replace it.

DECLARE @test NVARCHAR(50) = 'F-1084-002-04-009',
       @Replce NVARCHAR(3),
       @Value NVARCHAR(10)='00'

       SELECT @Replce=SUBSTRING(@test,12,2)

       SELECT REPLACE(@test,@Replce,@Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for variable length strings in the second-last element:

```
use tempdb

create table t
(
    v varchar(90)
)

insert t (v)
values  ('F-1084-002-04-009'),
        ('g-68236-6514652145-99-8127638176321637'),
        ('F-1084-002-0456-009')

select *,
    stuff(
        v,
        len(v) - (charindex('-', reverse(v), charindex('-', reverse(v), 0)+1) - 2),
        (charindex('-', reverse(v), charindex('-', reverse(v), 0)+1) - charindex('-', reverse(v), 0))-1,
        replicate('0', charindex('-', reverse(v), charindex('-', reverse(v), 0)+1) - charindex('-', reverse(v), 0) - 1)
    ) [Stuff]
from t
```